# Allow e-mail invite for user registration

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Has anyone ever explored allowing user registration in Orchard via invite links through e-mail? I want my admins to have a form where they can enter an e-mail address and sent registration invites to these people.

Comment: I don't think so. Would be a cool module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something very much like this. Most of the hard stuff is already built in to Orchard, it's just a case of utilizing what is already there.

1. Create a new User, using their email address as the username (only to act as a placeholder), and a random password. Their registration status should be set to "pending" to prevent them logging in until they have gone through the invite process. **
2. When it comes to sending the email, use the `IUserService.CreateNonce(...)` method to create a unique token for the new user. Use this nonce to create a URL, e.g. ~/invite/{nonce},  insert it into your email and send it out via `IMessageManager.Send(...)` (we actually trigger a rule to do this - it allows other stuff to be triggered at the same time and is also a hacky way of allowing the outgoing email to be customised using tokens ;)
3. The user then clicks the link and is sent to a controller that handles requests for ~/invite/{nonce} which will present a form allowing the user to enter their new username and password, storing the nonce in a hidden field.
4. Posting the form decrypts the nonce using `IUserService.DecryptNonce(...)` which gives you access to the username - you can then pass this to `IMembershipService.GetUser(...)` to get the corresponding `IUser`, and update it with the rest of the posted information (username, password using `IMembershipService.SetPassword(...)` etc).

IIRC most of this was accomplished by following how Orchard handles requests for lost passwords as it is essentially the same process - generating a unique URL for a given user and using that as a reference to retrieve the user once they have navigated to the URL.

** You don't need to create the User content item at this point, using the result from `IContentManager.New<UserPart>("User")` should suffice as long as you set the username. This would be useful if you didn't want to create the new user content item until the invite had been accepted at step 4.